ArcGIS 10.8.2 ModelBuilder, IterateFeatureClasses (RECURSIVE) is waiting forever
Iterator has not been working in the models I have built with ArcGIS Model Builder for the last month. It waits forever but it doesn't start. What could be the solution? I used it before without any problems.



How many *_poi_final datasets do you have in f:\ant ? Use file explorer to answer that. Also if you have many geodatabases in subfolders they will be searched to.

@Hornbydd there are 105 geodatabases and 315 poi_final feature classes in them.

i would copy one of those geodatabase into a new folder and test your model on that, if it runs quickly it would suggest your original structure is causing the slowness?

When running the model from within model builder, do an of the items turn red for any period of time at all?  If so, which ones?  What is the configuration of the iterator (maybe add a screenshot to show it).  Please add all new information to the original question post (edit it) so that people don't need to trawl through comments to find relevant information.

@Hornbydd without "RECURSIVE" no problem. It works.

@SonofaBeach actually no color change. It is waiting line screenshot. Iterator is for FeatureClasses and set for the main folder. Adding a screenshot for that to OP.
